# cross compilation of opencv for ARM 9 processor

Tags: opencv, arm

i need to cross compile opencv for ARM 9 processor. I have the tool chain for the processor but don't know how to cross compile. Can some on please tell me the procedure of cross compiling it for the arm board.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/03/arm-wrestling-with-opencv/

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [reference](http://www.airs.com/ian/configure/configure_5.html) for a explanation of cross compiling. If the source to be compiled supports the GNU build system it should be as easy as typing `./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi` instead of `./configure`, but all types of problems can occur (e.g. that the build system tries to run compiled code during the build process which is not possible since you are building ARM code on a X86 (I assume) machine).

That said I looked at the recipe for opencv in [OpenEmbedded](http://cgit.openembedded.org/cgit.cgi/openembedded/tree/recipes/opencv) and it has an impressive number of dependencies (stuff you need to build first); e.g. python, swig, glib (1). So I would say that you have some work ahead of you;)

(1) : These dependencies are those given by OpenEmbedded and you might be able to get away with fewer than those specified.

Comment: hi Andres,

I tried to cross compile the opencv using the toolchain i have.I had used the following link as reference. http://apollo.upc.es/humanoide/trac/wiki/OpenCv I got an error by loader as "segmentation fault" and as "Incompatible architecture". I don't know exactly what it meant. Can you tell me how to go about it.
By the by, i use opencv 1.0.0

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I followed the below instructions and was able to cross-compile OpenCV 2.4.2 on Ubuntu workstation. I am targeting ARM A8, but I beleive it should be similar if not exactly the same procedure.

[link](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Building_OpenCV_for_ARM_Cortex-A8)